# Can nspec run parallel tests?

Tags: webdriver, bdd, nspec, parallel-testing

I am looking for an Rspec-style tool for C# and have found Nspec.

I will be using it for Webdriver tests via Saucelabds so the ability to run tests in parallel is a key consideration.

Can this be done in Nspec?  Currently I use MBunit and this has great support for parallel testing and can only really consider a BDD approach which also supports this too.

I belive Specflow can be run in parallel but I am looking for an Rspec-style rather than Cucumber-style  tool

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there is no built in support to allow parallel execution of tests.  I've created a new issue on the github repo to possibly add this feature: https://github.com/mattflo/NSpec/issues/53